# Redirect to client or partner web page in jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I am facing a situation where REST service is suppose to redirect to client web page .

Problem is i will not know the clients url at coding time and moreover url is not suppose to be hard coded also  . Because the service should be useful for other clients also .

And the client cannot make page onLoad ajax call since client does not know the parameters to make ajax call .

Moreover the clients will have to stick to same page/Url if  the url is hardcoded in server side .

My idea is the client will send the URL path to service as parmeters . To which service will append the parameters and make a redirect .

Is this in accordance to REST architecture

Comment: Take it as an opinion , but I don't think that is possible. When client make rest call, it can only receive response. Any forwards you do on the request from your rest server is applicable for that server only. In short, for every call your rest server recieves, your container creates new http request object, not the same request object that your client sends. You can actually make call to the client webpage and return appropriate result from your rest service. Or you can create a url to the targeted page and return the url from service, which your client can use for redirect.

Comment: I am using jersey .Could you please give me a sample code in Jersey or which ever language or framework you prefer to make call to client web page and return  result

Answer (score 0):

Client Redirect can achieved in Jersey like this . If you want permanent redirect use 301 status,for temporary redirect use 307

```
@Path("/testRedirect")
@GET
public Response redirectTest()
{
    URI uri=UriBuilder.fromUri("http://www.google.com").build();
       return       Response.status(301).location(uri).build();

}
```